Нужно вывести всю информацию по принтерам с типом 'Jet', как вывести всё кроме самого типа без перечисления?
select * from printer where type = 'Jet';

Вывести все колонки, кроме колонки type? Только перечислив их. PS: за звёздочку в приличном обществе бьют ногами.

Гм, https://stackoverflow.com/q/729197/5045688 - народ всякие разные способы изобретает. И через временную таблицу с дропом колонки, и вьюху создать... А в некоторых диалектах такое уже реализовано, оказывается.
